# How to detect masked region on an image in PHP?

Tags: php, image, png, mask, masking

I have some images and each of them has a masked (transparent) rectangular region inside of the same size. How can I detect the coordinates of those regions? I searched for libraries but none of them does it. I want to put my QR codes instead of the masked part.

Answer (score 0):

I would try (not tested) to read the image and use a transparent color:

```
$src        = imagecreatefrompng("your-image.png");
$trans      = imageColorAllocateAlpha($src, 0, 0, 0, 127);
$transArray = imagecolorsforindex($src, $trans);
```

The I would read the image dimensions and check every pixel like this:

```
$width  = imagesx($src);
$height = imagesy($src);
for ($x = 0; $x < $width; $x++) {
   for ($y = 0; $y < $height; $y++) {
       $color  = imagecolorat($src, $x, $y);
       $colors = imagecolorsforindex($src, $color);
       if ($colors["alpha"] == $transArray["alpha"]) {
           // you have detected the first pixel of transparency
           // here you have to remember smallest $x and smallest $y
           // as well as biggest $x and biggest $y 
           // that should be your rectangle
       }
   }
 }
```

Comment: it worked! thank you very much, Marco. Now, I have to figure out how to apply this solution to rotated rectangles :D